# I get an error sometimes when i shoot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, gameobject

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been
>   destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should
>   either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
>   UnityEngine.Object.Internal_InstantiateSingle (UnityEngine.Object
>   data, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d9c061b1c154f5ae/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/UnityEngineObject.cs:44)
>   UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (UnityEngine.Object original, Vector3
>   position, Quaternion rotation) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/d9c061b1c154f5ae/Runtime/ExportGenerated/Editor/UnityEngineObject.cs:53)
>   Gun.Update () (at J:/W.A.R/Assets/Scripts/Gun.cs:16)

thats the error i get and here my code for the gun class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject bullet = null;
    public float bulletSpeed = 500f;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Mouse0)) {

            /*
             * Instantiate the bullet using the prefab and store it into the shot variable
             */

            GameObject shot = GameObject.Instantiate(bullet, transform.position + (transform.forward * 2), transform.rotation) as GameObject;

            /*
             * Adding force
             */
            shot.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to instantiate a bullet, however, you set the bullet to null, and in the code provided have not set it to something else. You cannot use a null object.

Comment: GameObject looks like a Base class, so probably you'd like a class Bullet that is of type GameObject, thus setting bullet = new Bullet().

Comment: @user1526784 Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, is that the bullet GameObject is null, and because it has not been set, when he tries to instantiate a null object, it throws an exception.

What you can do depends on the gameobject. You can use `GameObject.Find` to get the `GameObject` bullet and then assign that to the bullet var.

```
public GameObject bullet = GameObject.Find("NameOfTheBulletGameobject");
```

Another way you can do this is just drag the bullet gameobject onto the variable in the inspector.

```
public GameObject bullet;
```

Then, just take the actual bullet object and drag it onto the bullet variable in the script, in the inspector.

Hope it helps!